# What web server do you recommend?

Tags: iis, glassfish, webserver, wamp, apache-tomee

For work, I need a free web server system to host a few web apps that I will develop. The server will be installed on Windows. The apps will need to be able to access a bunch of files on the intranet, and massage them. Mostly 10 people at same time will be using the apps. I would prefer to write code in .NET as it contains many great APIs, but I am not sure if the latest IIS Express has any major restrictions (number of clients connected to web server or database, etc.).

The other web servers I looked at (which are not .NET) are:

- glassfish - seems that many are switching from it since Oracle stopped supporting it
- wamp servers - there are many, the other day I installed wampserver and wrote an app in PHP to see how good it is. I must say PHP was very slow accessing my intranet files and processing them.
- oracle weblogic server - never used it and have no idea how good it is
- tomee - seems to be new and I do not know how good it is for web application development

I am wondering what do you recommend?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

first of all I very invested in TomEE. That here here is my feedback:

weblo, TomEE and GlassFish are java servers where wamp is a php/httpd one. Depending what you target it can be enough to make a choice (investment for java is more important than php).

If you choose java then weblogic is not free AFAIK.

Then TomEE is very close to TomEE giving you just all the power you need for web development so it is a safe choice (you'll benefit from a lot of integration and tools for free).

GlassFish is not bad by itself and the best way to select one server is to test it with a small app in your environment IMO.